# When using VirtualAlloc why can I only allocate 1000 bytes as a minimum?

Tags: c++, winapi

When using `VirtualAlloc(0, 5, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);` I was hoping to only allocate 5 bytes which I can execute, read and write to, but when looking in x32dbg I see it allocated 1000 bytes in size. Why is this?

[image]

I think it's because a page is of size 1000 and that's the smallest unit of data for memory management in a virtual memory operating system. But I'd like to hear if it's true.

Comment: The answer can be found in documentation of the function that you are calling. No need to ask a question here. Just read the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc

Comment: i'm positive that it allocated 4096 bytes which is a typical page size. 1000 is hex number

Comment: Stupid of me not to read the docs, sorry. And thank you for the clarification, @ user7860670 !

Comment: Hi @Hummas, after understanding the question, you could write your own answer and [accept](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) to end this thread.